# Implicit way to create a Map in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I stumpled upon this example for creating a Map. But I am not able to compile / reproduce it.

```
data State r = S (Maybe r) (Map Char (State r))
data NumberSystem = Zero | Bin | Dec | Oct
automata :: State NumberSystem
automata = s where
    s   = S Nothing     ([(d,s10) | d <- ['1'..'9']] ++ [('0',s0)])
    s0  = S (Just Zero) ([('b',s2)] ++ [(d,s8) | d <- ['0'..'7']])
    s2  = S (Just Bin)  ([('0',s2),('1',s2)])
    ...
```

I used fromList to create it.

```
s   = S Nothing     (fromList([(d,s10) | d <- ['1'..'9']] ++ [('0',s0)]))
s0  = S (Just Zero) (fromList([('b',s2)] ++ [(d,s8) | d <- ['0'..'7']]))
```

So is there a implicit version for creating Maps in Haskell without using fromList in a way that the example above will compile?

Comment: Maybe https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/OverloadedLists?

Comment: How exactly could i implement this? My GHC version is 7.6.3

Comment: Are you sure this `Map` is actually `Data.Map.Map`?

Comment: @joschuck The simple answer is that without GHC 7.8 you can't use `OverloadedLists`.  Ensure that the `Map` type shown here is actually `Data.Map.Map` and not a locally defined type alias of `type Map k v = [(k, v)]`, as is often the case with example code.

Comment: You should provide the error message and complete code listing, so others would be able to provide clear and concise answer. It's possible to create Map with a code like this: `M.fromList [('a', "first"), ('b', "second")]`, where M is Data.Map imported qualified. Syntax you're using in a second code block is wrong, because haskell function application looks like `f x`, not `f(x)`.

Comment: @dredozubov, extra parentheses are ugly, but not really wrong.

Comment: @joschuck leftaroundabout isn't asking whether you have `Data.Map`. He is asking whether, *in the example code*, `Map` is referring to `Data.Map.Map`, which is not a property of your system. It could be a type alias like `type Map k v = [(k, v)]`, defined earlier in the example, or something similar.

Comment: @joschuck That wasn't the question either. The question was if you're sure that `Map` means `Data.Map.Map` _in whatever code you got this snippet from_.

Comment: @Cubic Yes, im 100% sure about that.

Comment: Slightly related. There is a package that defines a syntax for creating maps https://hackage.haskell.org/package/map-syntax